# как использовать значение переменной при конкатенации?

Tags: plsql

Подскажите, каким образом использовать значение переменной при конкатенации? Пробую примерно так:

```
v_val NUMBER;
v_val := 0;
   select count(1) into v_val from table1;

insert into table2 
      (SYSDATE, 1, concat('количество строк = ' , (select &v_val from dual)));
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
Error: PL/SQL: ORA-06544: PL/SQL: внутр.ошибка, аргументы: 
[ph2csql_strdef_to_diana:bind], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так

```
v_val NUMBER;
v_val := 0;
select count(1) into v_val from table1;

insert into table2 
      (SYSDATE, 1, 'количество строк = '||v_val);
```

Comment: Краткость конечно сестра таланта, но было бы неплохо сделать пример более похожим на реальный (лучше -- не просто реальный, а на исходный пример ТСа), а также привести [ссылку на документацию](https://oracleplsql.ru/concat-operator.html).

Comment: Сделал как у ТС